# find the domain of the function: $(\cos(x))^x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

find the domain of the function: $(\cos(x))^x$ I tried to find it and I found that any value of $x$ will be valid expect $-90, -270, - 450$ and so on; but I don't know how to express this.

Answer (score 2):

That is not correct: the definition of this function is
$$(\cos x)^x\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\mathrm e^{x\ln(\cos x)},$$
so $\cos x$ has to be positive,  i.e.
$$x\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbf Z}\biggl(-\frac\pi 2+2k\pi,\frac\pi 2+2k\pi\biggr).$$

Comment: $\cos{(2)}\lt0$ but $(\cos{(2)})^2=0.1731781895\dots$ is well defined.

Comment: Sure, for integer exponents, not for non-integer exponents.

Comment: what is the big U that you wrote

Comment: @Bernard Sure but your domain does not include $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I did not understand what you mean

Comment: The big U denotes the union of a family of sets, indexed by $\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @PeterForeman; It only includes the integers which are in one of the intervals I gave. You always may add the other integers, but they'll be isoltated points in the domain. Strictly speaking, $x^y$ is always defined by $x^y=\mathrm e^{y\ln x}$ and therefore is only defined  for $x>0$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=(\cos(x))^x$, if $x\geq 0$ is continuous everywhere. If $x<0$, must hold $\cos(x)\neq 0$, so $$x\neq-(2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}, k\in\mathbb{N}.$$ So, the domain of $f(x)$ is $$D_f=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x\neq-(2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}, k\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$

Comment: The problems come when $\cos x< 0$,not when $x<0$.  How will you raise a negative number to a non-integer power?

Answer (score 0):

When you see something like this, change the base. Here, we may write $$(\cos x)^x=e^{\log(\cos x)^x}.$$

Thus, what we want is that $(\cos x)^x$ be positive. Hence the maximal domain is the set of all $x$ for which $(\cos x)^x>0$ is true.

Comment: and then what is the domain?

Comment: @Mario Please read the last sentence.

Comment: I read it but what the domain if $(\cos (x))^x$ is negative

Comment: or x = $-\pi /2$

Comment: @Mario If $(\cos x)^x$ is negative then we have a multivalued complex function. I assumed OP wanted a real- valued, classical function.

Comment: Ok how to express the multivalues?? as a function

Comment: @Mario If $x=-π/2,$ then the function is not defined. Thus this point falls outside the domain.

Comment: @Mario The multivalued are not needed by OP here -- this is the *assumption* I made from context. We are talking about a real-valued *function,* which by definition is always single-valued.

Comment: Ok and - 3$\pi$/2 also is not defined how to express this???

Comment: can you look at the other comments you will understand what I mean??

Comment: @Mario Any value of $x$ not satisfying the inequality $(\cos x)^x>0$ is outside the domain of this mapping of some subset of $\mathrm R$ into $\mathrm R.$

Comment: Can you express that?

Comment: @Mario I've already expressed this. If you want it in set notation, you may write something like that the domain is $$\{x:x\in\mathrm R, (\cos x)^x>0\}.$$

Comment: yes I'm asking for this and this $(\cos x)^x < 0$

Comment: @Mario If $(\cos x)^x<0,$ then $\log (\cos x)^x$ is a is a multivalued, complex function. Do you want these too?

Comment: yes I want these too as a function of k and k $\in$ {1,2,3,4...}

Comment: Can you solve it ???

Comment: @Mario Well, then allow the argument of the logarithm to be negative. But then you no longer strictly have a function. So in set notation your domain would be the set $$\{x\in \mathrm R: (\cos x)^x\ne 0\}.$$

Comment: What do you think about this answer $D_f=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x\neq-(2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}, k\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: @Mario It doesn't capture cases when $\cos x=0$ and $x>0,$ or more comprehensively, cases when $(\cos x)^x=0.$